# When I refresh my page Home Page (private route) user data becomes null in firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

It works fine when you login or register for the first time and you are redirected to the Home page but when you try to refresh the home page it shows

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email') in Home.js

App.js:

```
function App () {
  let authentication =  getAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     onAuthStateChanged(authentication, (ur)=>{
       if (ur) {
         console.log(ur);
         setUser(ur);
         console.log(ur.email);
         navigate('/home');
       }
       else {
         navigate('/roothome');
       }

    })
    
  }, [])
```

Home.js

```
export default function Home(props) {
   let navigate = useNavigate();
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.user) {
            console.log(props.user)
            navigate('/home')
        }

        if (!props.user) {
            navigate('/login')
        }

    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome {props.user.email}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```